# sample level loss calculation access before calculating final loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a multi-output model and need to check the sample-wise loss of each output branch before calculating the final training loss. How can I achieve this? Right now I am using the model.fit() method and this gives batch-wise total loss and individual loss for each branch.

Below is custom function I am using:

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
    # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
    # on what you pass to `fit()`.
    x, y = data

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
        # Compute the loss value
        # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
        loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

    # Compute gradients
    trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
    # Update weights
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
    # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
    # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
    return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

Comment: What loss function are you using? Usually, losses have an argument `reduction` to specify how the individual losses should be aggregated (e.g. see [MSE](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredError)). You can try setting this value to `tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE` (see options [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Reduction)).

Comment: @rvinas I am using the binary-crossentropy loss function. I want to have access to the loss from each output for each sample and whichever output/branch has a lower loss that branch gets the loss_weight of 1 and the other branch gets a loss_weight of 0.1. Finally, the weighted losses sum up to give the final loss for that sample.

Comment: When you compile the model, if you use the loss function [`BinaryCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy) with `reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE`, does this return the non-aggregated losses?

Comment: @rvinas using loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(reduction=Reduction.NONE) or without using (reduction=Reduction.NONE) it shows same verbose:
1/45 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.7725 - rf8_scale_loss: 0.6931 - rf4_scale_loss: 0.6931 - rf2_scale_loss: 0.6931 - rf1_scale_loss: 0.6932 - 

It shows total loss as sum of all four output branch losses I,e loss =rf8_scale_loss + rf4_scale_loss + rf2_scale_loss + rf1_scale_loss. Also, I am not sure if these losses are sample wise loss or batch-wise loss.

Comment: @rvinas Now I am getting loss for each branch/output after compiling the model with run_eagerly=True argument. But, I am facing new issue now. code is calculating all gradient values as "None" if I use : loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE).(y, y_pred) instead of loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

Comment: That's weird. How did you define your model? Could this be because of a non-differentiable operation or a disconnected computational graph?

Comment: @rvinas I have compiled a functional API model. Detail about the loss can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949567/all-gradient-values-calculated-as-none-if-using-bce-loss-manually). I am not sure whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the non-aggregated losses, set the argument `reduction` of your loss function to `tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE` (see options [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Reduction)). For example, if your loss function is [`BinaryCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy), you can instantiate it as follows:

```
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
```

Then, calling `bce` will yield the element-wise losses that you are after.

Comment: Yes, I did that and I am getting output branch-wise loss values. But, I am having a "None" value error while calculating the gradients.