# All Gradient values calculated as "None" if using BCE loss manually

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a multi-output model where I need to weigh all output losses before calculating the overall loss. I have a customized `model. fit()` [training loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit) to achieve this.

As I need to calculate the sample-wise loss for all four outputs and fuse these sample-wise losses after applying weight, I have customized the standard code. Now, the loss is calculating sample-wise but while calculating the gradient, all gradient values are calculated as "None". I tried to put `tape.watch(loss)` also, but it is not working. Kindly, help me to fix this issue.

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        print(tf.executing_eagerly())
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x, y = data
        alpha = 0.1
        loss = 0
        y_pred_all = []

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
            for spl in range(1 if np.shape(x)[0] == None else np.shape(x)[0]):
                tape.watch(loss)
                tape.watch(loss_mean)
                tape.watch(loss_element)
                x_spl = np.reshape(x[spl], (1, np.shape(x)[1], np.shape(x)[2], np.shape(x)[3]))
                y_pred = self(x_spl, training=True)  # Forward pass
                y_pred_all.append(y_pred)
                loss_element = bce(y[spl], y_pred)
                loss_mean = [np.mean(loss_element[0]), np.mean(loss_element[1]), np.mean(loss_element[2]), np.mean(loss_element[3])]
                id = np.argmin(loss_mean)
                for i, ele in enumerate(loss_mean):
                    if i == id:
                        loss_mean[i] *= 1
                    else:
                        loss_mean[i] *= alpha

                loss = loss + np.sum(loss_mean)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred_all)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

**UPDATE**
I did few changes as suggested by **@rvinas**
Now it is calculating the gradient without any error but I am not sure if the changes I did are correct or not:

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # print(tf.executing_eagerly())
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x, y = data
        alpha = 0.1
        loss = tf.Variable(0, dtype='float32')
        y_pred_all = []

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
            for spl in tf.range(1 if tf.shape(x)[0] == None else tf.shape(x)[0]):
                loss_mean=tf.convert_to_tensor([])
                x_spl =  tf.reshape(x[spl], (1, tf.shape(x)[1], tf.shape(x)[2], tf.shape(x)[3]))
                y_pred = self(x_spl, training=True)  # Forward pass
                y_pred_all.append(y_pred)
                loss_element = bce(y[spl], y_pred)
                loss_mean = [tf.reduce_mean(loss_element[0]), tf.reduce_mean(loss_element[1]), tf.reduce_mean(loss_element[2]), tf.reduce_mean(loss_element[3])]

                id = tf.argmin(loss_mean)
                for i, ele in enumerate(loss_mean):
                    if i == id:
                        loss_mean[i] = tf.multiply(loss_mean[i], 1)
                    else:
                        loss_mean[i] = tf.multiply(loss_mean[i], alpha)

                loss = tf.add(loss, tf.add(tf.add(tf.add(loss_mean[0],loss_mean[1]), loss_mean[2]), loss_mean[3]))

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred_all)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

Comment: You should not be using NumPy operations (e.g. np.sum, np.reshape, ...) - this results in a disconnected graph. Instead use tensorflow operations only.

Comment: @rvinas can you please suggest what should be done here to fix the issue. I am very new to TF. So, I do not have info about the TF operations. I used NumPy operations here I need to manipulate/weigh each output branch loss.

Comment: At first glance, it is difficult to understand how you're weighting each element of the loss. Ideally, you should have a tensor `weights` with the same shape as `loss` (i.e., `(batch_size, nb_elements)`) and compute the final weighted loss with something along the lines of `tf.reduce_mean(weights * loss)`. The "for loop" within the gradient tape block should ideally be avoided.

Comment: @rvinas Actually, I am trying to implement a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.06878.pdf) and the paper says that we will calculate the sample-wise loss for each scale/output. In my case, # of outputs is 4. So, whichever loss(out of 4 output losses) is smallest (for a sample) gets a weight of 1 and the remaining three losses get the weight of 0.1. For example, For a sample, if output_loss = [2, 5, 1, 3] (here 4 elements in the list represents 4 loss values corresponding to 4 outputs), according to the weighing logic final_loss = (2*0.1) + (5*0.1) + (1 * 1) + (3*0.1)

Comment: I hope the provided solution helps - note that I am only using TF operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NaN gradients occur because you are using NumPy operations (e.g. `np.sum`, `np.reshape`, ...), which results in a disconnected graph. Instead one needs to implement the logic using tensorflow operations only.

---

For example, one could implement the weightings described in the comments section as follows:

```
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # Compute element-wise losses
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    losses = bce(y, y_pred)  # Shape=(bs, 4)

    # Find maximum loss for each sample
    idx_max = tf.argmax(losses, axis=-1)  # Shape=(bs,)
    idx_max_onehot = tf.one_hot(idx_max, depth=y.shape[-1])  # Shape=(bs, 4)

    # Create weights tensor
    weight_max = 1
    weight_others = 0.1
    weights = idx_max_onehot * weight_max + (1 - idx_max_onehot) * weight_others

    # Aggregate losses
    losses = tf.reduce_sum(weights * losses, axis=-1)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
```

Comment: What is "a" in "depth=a.shape[-1]" ?

Comment: In this case, the depth is 4, i.e. the number of output elements (`a` should be `y` instead, sorry).

Comment: This code gives error at : losses = tf.reduce_sum(weights * losses, axis=-1)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [4,2,6] vs. [4,2,256] [Op:Mul]

Comment: Wasn't the shape of `y` `(bs, 4)`? And why is the shape of `losses` `(4, 2, 256)`?

Comment: Here in (4, 2, 256), I guess **2** is the batch_size, **4** is the no. of outputs, and **256** is sequence length/no of time frames, and **y** (ground truth) is the framewise label. So, the length of y is equal to the sequence length.

Comment: So you are outputting sequences rather than multiple labels? Usually, the first dimension corresponds to the batch size, the second to the number of time points (i.e. sequence length), and the last to the dimensionality of each time point. I am not sure how the weighting blends in if you are outputting sequences.

Comment: Yes, as I am working on a sound event detection task I need to input target for each time frame.

Comment: Right, but how do you want to weight the elements exactly? (considering the outputs are sequences)

Comment: Ok, I have 4 parallel branches(diff resolution features) from different layers of an Hourglass model. Each branch o/p is of the same feature resoln. These branches o/p the prediction at different scales. So I am using adaptive fusion algo. to get a fused prediction. In this algo sample-wise performance is calculated for each branch. The branch with the lowest loss for the sample gets a weight factor of 1 other gets 0.1. These factors are multiplied with sample-wise loss of each branch. So final o/p is a weighted sum of all 4 branches for all samples in 1 fwd pass and is repeated in nxt epoch.

Comment: more detail is in paper <https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.06878.pdf> as the comment section has fixed character length. :(

Comment: Accepting this answer as the main problem of "None" is solved by using TensorFlow operations instead of the Numpy operations.