# Why is Tensorflow unable to make a Gradient here?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get this warning (twice):
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['my_dense_layer/why is this of not work:0'] when minimizing the loss.

I want to train the weights in self.wm. But apparently it just doesn't work in this case.
How this works is just basically a remaping and reshaping to get a Matrix with which to calculate the output. I think it's still just a linear transformation in the end.
with tf.GradientTape I am getting an approperiate result. But when I run through a network I get a warning. Maybe somethings wrong with the way it's executed?

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.wm=self.add_weight("why is this of not work",shape=[1,4])
        self.mapper = tf.constant([[[float(i == k + (2 * (j ** 2))) for i in range(self.num_outputs)] for j in range(4)] for k in range(input_shape[1])],dtype='float32')
        self.kernel = tf.matmul(self.wm, self.mapper)
        self.kern = tf.reshape(self.kernel, (input_shape[1],self.num_outputs))

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        f=tf.matmul(inputs,self.kern)
        return f
```

```
model = krs.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(256,activation='sigmoid'),
        layers.Flatten(),
        customlayers.MyDenseLayer(64),
        layers.Dense(10),
    ]
)

model.compile(
    loss=krs.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=krs.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
```

EDIT: Removed Numpy

Comment: Don't use numpy in your custom layer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All Gradient values calculated as "None" if using BCE loss manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949567/all-gradient-values-calculated-as-none-if-using-bce-loss-manually)

Comment: I can avoid using numpy, but this doesn't solve the problem. 
Also I forgot to mention the standalone gradient tape works fine with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, it seems the problem here was that I've done linalg operations inside the build function rather than the call function. My hypothesis is that the gradienttape only takes the call function into account.

```
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.wm=self.add_weight("why is this of not work",shape=[1,4])
        self.mapper = tf.constant([[[float(i == k + (2 * (j ** 2))) for i in range(self.num_outputs)] for j in range(4)] for k in range(input_shape[1])],dtype='float32')


    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        self.kernel = tf.matmul(self.wm, self.mapper)
        self.kern = tf.reshape(self.kernel, (input_shape[1],self.num_outputs))
        f=tf.matmul(inputs,self.kern)
        return f
```

works just fine.
It's a little bit of a letdown though, since this is a computational disaster to recalculate the kernel for every pass. I'd appreciate some additional clarification if possible.

EDIT: Come to think about it, if TF would change the weights, the kernel would not be able to update, since the update is (incorrectly) coded in the build function. So it makes sense for Tensorflow to throw an Error there.

Comment: I was about to write an answer, but your edit basically gets the point. `call` uses `self.kernel`, but that is actually a tensor with a fixed value, which is computed when `build` is called. Tensorflow doesn't "remember" that it was computed from `self.wm` and the update for the latter cannot be computed.